# I need to access/edit the HTML code of page Templates which are written in PHP in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm getting confused on how to get the HTML code when the website is already made in page templates. In page templates there is all PHP written which is fetching HTML by itself no html is shown there. I need to get my hands on HTML of the page.

Comment: I wordpress they are using small small html snippet in different different php file. You not edit whole html in one place.

Comment: Ty for your response!. I need to change 1 picture only but HTML is not showing up in the template's php file. The PHP file getting header,footer and the content of html from where?

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit a single HTML page.

By cons you can customize your themes, modifying PHP files (containing your HTML) that can expand only with a single HTML page.

To edit theme files:

`Appearance -> Editor`

Comment: I want to edit the template which is used in the page not the whole page. I know where my template is but it is in php, the designing the pictures are not there in that php file nor any other file is fetching there. The thing is i need to customise that template.
BTW thanks for your comment.

Comment: Find the name of the image tag you want to edit. Then access to your site in FTP and search among all the files, it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find only HTML code inside Wordpress theme. Wordpress is based on PHP and all are written by PHP.

If you have to customize the template, you can learn [How to create a custom template page?](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/)

And also this is the template documentation [Wordpress Pages template Doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Your all js, html and also php are in .php files. There's no way you want only to see/edit html only.

If you want to edit specific html, first check your element class/id with Inspector by pressing F12 or CTRL+Shift+I and then go looking the element class/id on the php files by Appearance > Editor.

For example, you want edit your picture element class/id on the homepage, it should be in index.php (note that: some developer theme have different way), if on the content page then the element is around single.php and content.php files